# Is there any way to keep whitespaces before text in iText7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I've added a Text object that start with whitespaces to the Paragraph object,

but the whitespace of paragraph is removed in iText7(7.0.4).

It looks like left trim. Is this a specification of Paragraph?

Is there any way to keep whitespaces before text?

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(new Text("  abc")); // Only "abc" appears in pdf
```

Comment: Maybe `"\u00a0\u00a0abc"` (hard space)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iText will trim spaces.
But it will not remove non-breaking spaces.

```
File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "output.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Lorem Ipsum"));
layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum"));
layoutDocument.close();
```

Comment: Does not properly answer the posed question. Clarify how to add non-breaking spaces and I'll lift my downvote.

Comment: NBSP cannot be used because it occupy space, but I can prevent left-trim by adding a NULL character before the paragraph. Your advice have been very helpful for me. Thank you for your kind answer.

<code>
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("\u0000").add(new Text("  abc"));
</code>

Comment: For anyone wanting to add null character (C#): `new Paragraph(char.MinValue + "         My test string")`   This worked in that it kept left trim of string.

Answer (score 5):

Follow steps:

1. Extend TextRenderer class
2. Override trimFirst method(but do nothing in it)
3. Pass an object of this class to Text.setTextRenderer method

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me. props!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution based on anirban banerjee's answer. I made the following class:

```
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.*;

public class CodeRenderer extends TextRenderer {

    public CodeRenderer(Text textElement) {
        super(textElement);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CodeRenderer((Text) getModelElement());
    }

    @Override
    public void trimFirst() {}
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
Text text = new Text(string);
text.setNextRenderer(new CodeRenderer(text));
document.add(new Paragraph(text));
```

The result is that all whitespaces are kept.

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me. props!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding a "ghost" character (white font) after the white spaces. Like this:

```
p = new Paragraph("Text: ").setFontSize(10);
        p.add(new Text("some text    ").setUnderline());
        p.add(new Text(".").setFontColor(whiteColor));
        document.add(p);
```