# Itext7 java how to Override trimFirst() on IElement

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I would like to Override the trimfirst () method of an IElement returned by HtmlConverter (it appears that whitespace is eliminated by the HtmlConverter class).

Assuming you have a string like this:

```
Hello                  my name is Roger !
```

after running these lines of code :

```
List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(stringBuilder.toString(),cvProp);
           
for (IElement tagParag : lst) {
    p = (Paragraph) tagParag;
}
```

The result of text is this :

```
Hello my name is Roger!
```

This is the string before passing by the converter :

```
<p style='font-family:times-roman;font-size:10.5pt'>dalla notifica del presente atto di ingiunzione l'importo dovuto per complessivi Euro                             come qui di seguito specificati:</p>
```

What happened to the white spaces? There should have been some trim.

In another case I had used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68935671/18323778.

How can I adopt a solution like this on an IElement Object. Also is it the trimFirst () method that you think removes whitespace? Or there is some other method that removes the whitespace?

Comment: You are starting with HTML (otherwise you wouldn't use the `HtmlConverter`) and HTML already implies that multiple space characters collapse to a single one for displaying, doesn't it?

Comment: Please tag the language of your code for better question discoverability.

Comment: Oh my god it's true !!! I copied the piece of hml in an .html file, in fact the browser eliminates the spaces, as you say. So the problem is hmtl ... solutions?!?!

Comment: I tried using the '&emsp;'  for tabulator. In the browser it works but Itext HtmlConverter ignores this.

Comment: *"So the problem is hmtl ... solutions?!?!"* - well, I would have voted for not using HTML to start with. Using Alexey's answer to enforce a different interpretation of consecutive spaces is easier for you to use, though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` CSS property declaration to preserve your whitespaces and avoid collapsing while still wrapping your text over the lines:

```
<p style='font-family:times-roman; white-space: pre-wrap; font-size:10.5pt'>dalla notifica del presente atto di ingiunzione l'importo dovuto per complessivi Euro                             come qui di seguito specificati:</p>
```

Visual result in the PDF:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Alexey Subach your answer is the right solution. I changed the code and it works great. 
So the problem is not Itext .... I apologize to the developers :-)